# Movimiento de tres puntitos

Tags: javascript

Quiero  mover los tres puntitos consecutivamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero no se mueven verticalmente, logre moverlos horizontalmente

> encontre lo que quiero pero con css
>   https://codepen.io/mattonit/pen/vLoddq
>
> se puede con javascript?

```js
let rootElements = document.querySelectorAll("div.dot");
let i = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  i++;
  if (i % 10 > 2) {
    i = 0;
  }
  rootElements[i % 10].style.margin = "0px";
  for (let j = 0; j < rootElements.length; j++) {
    if (j !== i) {
      rootElements[j].style.margin = "-1px";
    }
  }
}, 500);
```

```css
.dot {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="dot">⚫</div>
  <div class="dot">⚫</div>
  <div class="dot">⚫</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He hecho algunos cambios en tu código:

- El índice `i` se calcula a partir del número de elementos de `rootElements` (en el código original se está haciendo módulo de 10 y luego comparar con 2, cuando en este caso particular un módulo de 3 o del número de elementos de `rootElements` sería más conveniente).
- En lugar de moverlos cambiando el margen, les he puesto una posición relativa a los círculos y se cambia el valor del `top`. De ese modo cuando se mueve uno de los círculos, los otros círculos no se mueven (o no un movimiento no esperado).
- Con CSS le he dado un estado inicial y un valor de `transition`, entonces con JavaScript, teniendo en cuenta que sabemos qué elemento está activo (`i`) lo único que tenemos que hacer es quitarle los estilos (para que vuelva al estado inicial), avanzar el valor de `i` y darle los estilos que queramos al siguiente elemento a mover. Eliminando el bucle `for` que hay en el código que no parece ser realmente necesario.

Aquí puedes ver una demo:

```js
let rootElements = document.querySelectorAll("div.dot");
let i = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  // cambiamos el elemento activo al estado original
  rootElements[i].style = "";
  
  // actualizamos el valor del elemento activo
  i=++i%rootElements.length;
  
  // cambiamos la posición y opacidad del elemento activo
  rootElements[i].style.top = "0px";
  rootElements[i].style.opacity = 1;
}, 350);
```

```css
.dot {
  display: inline-block;
  top: 4px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.35s;
  opacity: 0.4;
  font-size: 32px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="dots">
  <div class="dot">&#9679;</div>
  <div class="dot">&#9679;</div>
  <div class="dot">&#9679;</div>
</div>
```

La animación no es exactamente como la de Facebook (que parece la que tratas de replicar) porque no hay una pausa al final o los puntos nunca están los 3 en movimiento (ambas cosas se podrían conseguir con una segunda función y usando `setTimeout` con diferentes tiempos en lugar de `setInterval`).

Answer (score 1):

Solo bastaría con quitar la propiedad de margin -1 px y ponerla como margin auto para que se acomoden los elementos tanto vertical como horizontal y el display en vez de que se comporte con en línea que se como en bloque

quedando así mira:

```
.dot {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Quedando el siguiente resultado

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    <style>
    .dot {
      display: block;
      margin: auto;
    }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="padre">
      <div class="dot">*</div>
      <div class="dot">*</div>
      <div class="dot">*</div>
    </div>
      <script>
        let rootElements = document.querySelectorAll("div.dot");
    let i = 0;
    
    setInterval(() => {
      i++;
      if (i % 10 > 2) {
        i = 0;
      }
      rootElements[i % 10].style.margin = "0px";
      for (let j = 0; j < rootElements.length; j++) {
        if (j !== i) {
          rootElements[j].style.margin = "-1px";
        }
      }
    }, 500);
       
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: edite mi pregunta, adjunte una imagen, revisalo porfavor

Answer (score 1):

No creo que se muevan mas bien cambian de color.

```js
let rootElements = document.querySelectorAll("div.dot");

let i = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  i++;
  if (i % 10 > 2) {
    i = 0;
  }
  for (let j = 0; j < rootElements.length; j++) {
    if (j !== i) {
      rootElements[j].style.color = "#999999";
      rootElements[j].style.animationName = "goingUp";
    }else{
      rootElements[j].style.color = "#555555"; 
      rootElements[j].style.animationName = "goingDown";
   }
  }
}, 300);
```

```css
.dot {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: -1px;
  position: relative;
  animation: goingUp 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes goingUp {
    from {transform: translateY(0px);}
    to {transform: translateY(10px);}
}

@keyframes goingDown {
    from {transform: translateY(10px);}
    to {transform: translateY(0px);}
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="dot">⚫</div>
  <div class="dot">⚫</div>
  <div class="dot">⚫</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Personalmente, si la animación que buscas es siempre la misma, usaría un gif animado. Te ahorras código y problemas.
Si te hace gracia hacerlo con JS, pon cada punto en un objeto distinto con la propiedad CSS position:relative y juega con su propiedad top.
Algo parecido a esto:

```js
var ondas=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,4,3,2,1];
var dots=document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
var indices=[];
for (var i=0; i<dots.length;i++)
  indices.push(Math.floor(ondas.length/dots.length*i));

function bucle(){
  for (var i=0; i<dots.length;i++) {
    var j=indices[i];
    dots[i].style.top=ondas[j]+"px";
    if (++j>=ondas.length) j=0;
    indices[i]=j;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(bucle);
}
requestAnimationFrame(bucle);
```

```css
.dot {position:relative};
```

```html
<div>
 <span class="dot">*</span>
 <span class="dot">*</span>
 <span class="dot">*</span>
 <span class="dot">*</span>
 <span class="dot">*</span>
 <span class="dot">*</span>
 <span class="dot">*</span>
 <span class="dot">*</span>
 <span class="dot">*</span>
</div>
```